# Not receiving RING indication on incoming call

Tags: java, at-command

I'm trying to alert user about incoming call but I'm not receiving RING unsolicited response by phone on incoming call. I'm connected to phone via bluetooth through handsfree profile and I'm sending at commands through output stream. When i connect to my car radio and then test on pc it works but after few re-connections it stops working. Can someone tell what's turning off when I disconnect and connect to same phone few times ? And how can I turn it back on ? The other phone I'm trying it with have never been connected to any car radio before and it doesn't indicate RING either. I'm trying it with iPhone and android and neither works all other commands i send to them works the same doesn't matter which phone I'm trying it with.

```
String word = "AT+BRSF=255\r";
            byte[] command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            String answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("2. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

           word = "AT+BAC=1\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("3. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+CIND=?\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("4. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+CIND?\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("5. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+CMER=3,0,0,1\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("6. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+NREC=0\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("7. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            word = "AT+CHLD=?\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("8. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+COPS=3,0\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("8. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+COPS?\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("9. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+CBC=?\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("10. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

           word = "AT+CLIP=1\r\n";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("11. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+CCWA=1\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);
            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("14. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+CGMM\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("12. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+CGMI\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);

            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("12. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+CMEE=1\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);
            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("13. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+BIND=1,2\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);
            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("15. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+BIND=?\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);
            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("16. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+BIND?\r";
            command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);
            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("17. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");

            Thread.sleep(150);

            word = "AT+CPIN?\r";
command = word.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            outputStream.write(command);
            answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("18. command");
            while (!answer.equals("OK") && !answer.equals("ERROR"))
            {
                System.out.println(answer);
                answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(answer+"\n");
```

This are the commands I'm sending every time I connect to phone int the order I'm sending them. I'm doing this in Java.

```
while (true){
             try {
                    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    if (line.contains("RING")) {
                        System.out.println("Incoming call");
                        bufferedReader.readLine();
                    }
                    System.out.println(line);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

this is how I read the output from phone.
To answer what phone I'm using I'm trying to do it to work with any android phone or iPhone.
And the output

```
+CIEV: 3,1

RING

+CLIP: "+123456789",145,,,"  +123456789"

RING

+CIEV: 3,0
```

this is the output i expect

```
+CIEV: 3,1

+CIEV: 3,0
```

this is what i get.

Comment: When you write, it's a good idea to call `flush()`. I've no idea of your protocol, but you must know it inside out, because if you don't and are reading in a loop and looking for the wrong reponse, all that will happen is that it will block the thread, possibly for evermore.

Comment: thank you yeah it happened that it got blocked but after sending all the commands I'm just reading anything that comes so it's not getting blocked cause that happened few times but i fixed it. And as it is written first two or three connections it works and after that it does not anymore. But the flush() is good point i forgot about it

Comment: Did you solve with `flush()`? Otherwise: 1) what is the output of your program? (please write the log explaining where the call is supposed to be received. 2) What is the part of the code that is supposed to "catch" the RING? 3) What device are you using? (better: link to the relevant AT command guide).

Comment: No `flush()` didn't help. I added answer where I wrote to all you asked @RobertoCaboni

Comment: Please, instead of writing it in a not-an-answer edit those info in the question itself (and delete the answer).

Comment: I forgot i can edit my question and one more thing I tried a lot of different commands but most of them returned ERROR. Commands that are in my code all return OK